# response.body().string(); is Null

Tags: java, android, spring, retrofit

I try create an application on Android with authentication using Retrofit2. But `response.body().string();` is Null. What am i doing wrong?

My RetrofitClient.java

```
package com.example.androidauthenticationapp;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static  final String BASE_URL = "http://194.58.97.124:8080/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient () {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public API getAPI () {
        return retrofit.create(API.class);
    }

}
```

And RegisterActivity.java with Null response.

```
package com.example.androidauthenticationapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etUsername, etPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etRUserName);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etRPassword);

        findViewById(R.id.btnRegister).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.tvLoginLink).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String userName = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (userName.isEmpty()) {
            etUsername.setError("Username is required");
            etUsername.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
            etPassword.setError("Password is required");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getAPI()
                .createUser(new User(userName, password));

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                String s = "";
                try {
                    if (response.body() != null){
                    s = response.body().string();
                }} catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (s.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered. Please login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

If i delete a line `if (response.body() != null){`, the app crashes. I can add Spring code, if needed. But through the console, the server responds correctly (SUCCESS).

Comment: so it's not empty, it's null?

Comment: use scalarconvertorfactory for string response in retroclient method()

Comment: try to retrieve and log in console the response status first.